# Show that any conjugate pair of complex numbers (with non-zero imaginary part) cannot be the spectrum of any 2x2 matrix with real, nonnegative entries

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, complex-numbers, spectral-theory

My professor showed me this in her office today but I didn't like her method and wanted to use another method.

So, I computed the characteristic polynomial of some arbitrary $2 \times 2$ matrix with nonnegative entries $a,b,c,d$, and solved for its two eigenvalues using the quadratic formula.

Then I equated the conjugate pair of complex numbers (with non-zero imaginary part) to the two eigenvalues, and am trying to derive some contradiction at this point.  But, I'm stuck.

My professor had used some complexification process and showed that the realizing matrix must have certain trigonometric entries (she mentioned rotation matrices), and then derived an impossibility.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Let the complex numbers be $u\pm i v$. If those are the zeros of the characteristic polynomial of the real $2\times 2$-matrix $A$, then the trace of $A$ must be $2u$, and the determinant must be $u^2 + v^2$. Look at these constraints to see that some entry of $A$ must be negative if $v\neq 0$.

Comment: Awesome comment, @DanielFischer.  I am able to show it now from your suggestion, as well as with my original method.  Thanks so much :)

Comment: The current (self-destructive) edit perhaps makes this question not a duplicate, but it definitely makes it worth closing because it is unclear (as all incomplete sentences are). Since I don't see a reason to bother with that, I'll just vote for leaving it closed.

Comment: Hi @DanielFischer, I think I spoke too soon and did not find the contradiction correctly.  I assumed that $a=d=u$ so that $a+d = 2u$ then looked at the determinant equation, subtracted off $u^2$ from both sides and was left with $-bc = v^2$, from which I said that if $v$ were not $0$, then either $b$ or $c$ must be negative, giving us the desired contradiction.  Is this incorrect?  Thanks,

Comment: You can't just assume that $a = d = u$. But you can write $a = u+h,\, d = u-h$ with some $h \in \mathbb{R}$. Then you are left with $-bc = h^2 + v^2$, and that forces one of $b$ and $c$ to be negative if $v \neq 0$ (or $h \neq 0$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume your matrix is

$$
M=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
a & b\\
c & d\\\end{array} \right).
$$

The the characteristic polynomial is

$$
|M-\lambda I|=(a-x)(d-x)-bc
$$

and setting the characteristic polynomial to zero yields the solution

$$
\lambda = \frac 12 \left(a + d \pm\sqrt{4bc + (a-d)^2}\right).
$$

The eigenvalues are only imaginary if

$$
4bc + (a-d)^2<0
$$

but by assumption $b>0$ and $c>0$. The second term is positive as long as $a$ and $d$ are real (or their complex parts cancel). Thus, the eigenvalues must be real.

Answer (score 1):

For a $2 \times 2$ matrix $A$, the characteristic equation is $x^2 - \text{Tr}(A)x + |A| = 0$. If this equation has complex roots, then the discriminant is negative. But if you assume A = [a,b;c,d], then $\text{Tr}(A)^2 - 4|A| = (a-d)^2 + 4bc \geq 0$!!

Answer (score -1):

Hint: Calculate the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial of 
$$\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}$$
after some easy calculations to be $$\frac{1}{4}\left((a-d)^2+4bc\right).$$

Remark: Complex-conjugated eigenvalues may only exist if $bc<0$ regardless of the signs of $a$ and $b$.